# Magento 2.1.3 Import configurable products

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-2.1.3

I use import function to import some configurable products. But after I import, the configurable products is not listed.

Here is the csv file I used. Please help me fix this.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4dGujTqvOsHREJ5OFVMb01NRkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the case, but keep all configurable products at the end of  the CSV file. Actually, I import configurable products seperately after simple products import.